# calling api in golang error 400 bad request

Tags: go, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting the following error. What is wrong the code below written in golang? Any idea?

> &{400 Bad Request 400 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html;
>   charset=us-ascii] Date:[Wed, 15 Aug 2018 16:14:34 GMT]
>   Content-Length:[311]] 0xc42005c280 311 [] true false map[]
>   0xc4200fe000 0xc4200a62c0}

---

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret?query=a two level microprogram simulator&complete=0&count=10&model=latest")
```

Answer (score 1):

While there's something wrong with the Go code (`my-key` looks weird in particular), the problem is that you need to escape the spaces in the query parameter:

```
$ curl 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret?query=a two level microprogram simulator&complete=0&count=10&model=latest'
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

After escaping the spaces with `%20`, we get the expected access error:

```
$ curl 'https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret?query=a%20two%20level%20microprogram%20simulator&complete=0&count=10&model=latest'

{"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
```

It is best to let Go handle this:

```
import "net/url"

base_url := "https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/interpret"

var v url.Values
v.Add("query", "a two level microprogram simulator")
v.Add("complete", "0")
v.Add("count", "10")
v.Add("model", "latest")

url := base_url + "?" + v.Encode()
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually earlier I also figured it out as well. So what I suggest is to simply add fol
url.QueryEscape("a two level microprogram simulator")